# what is the purpose of index param inside getRangeAt() function?

Tags: javascript

what is the purpose of `index` param inside `getRangeAt()` function ?
As I can see - only one single selection is possible
Is there any scenario with multiple selections and having the `index` param usefull ?

```js
$('button').on('click', function(){
  var sel = document.getSelection();
  var a = sel.getRangeAt(0).toString();
  console.log(a);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>lorem ipsum</div>
<div>dolor sit</div>
<div>amet</div>
<button>CLICK</button>
```

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Selection/getRangeAt and https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Range ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the [documentation for `rangeCount`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Selection/rangeCount)

> A user can normally only select one range at a time, so the rangeCount will usually be 1. Scripting can be used to make the selection contain more than one range.
>
> Gecko browsers allow multiple selections across table cells. Firefox
> allows to select multiple ranges in the document by using Ctrl+click
> (unless the click occurs within an element that has the display:
> table-cell CSS property assigned).

Comment: ok, thanks. I think - this explanation should be placed on `getRangeAt` page

Comment: @qadenza On the [getRangeAt](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Selection/getRangeAt) page it refers to [rangeCount](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Selection/rangeCount) at the parameters section